# What is the name given to the triangle patterns when marking on a table of integers that gives an integer when one is divided by the other?

Tags: integers

Sorry I don’t know anything about math I’m just looking for the name given to the pattern of triangles that appear when you make a table of integers by integers and mark on which can be divided by the other to give an integer.

Thanks

Comment: We could call it a "divisibility-table" or a "factor-table"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are referring to all the points $(n,m)$ with integer coordinates such that $n$ divides $m$. Depending on how you look at it, there do appear to be patterns in the discrete set of points and some of them could be described as triangular. This pattern has no specific name that I know of.

Comment: Yes that’s it thanks, I thought it was an interesting pattern especially that the first point of each triangle is a square number. Do the triangles relate to the gap between Prime numbers?

Comment: What you mean by "first  point ... is a square number"? How can a point be a square number? Your description of the triangles is not specific enough to answer your question more fully.